# Scapy/Python not grabbing outgoing packets

Tags: python, wireless, scapy

Sorry, I must be missing something, just adapting a very simple script :

```
from scapy.all import *

def packet_callback(packet):
    if packet[TCP].payload:
         print '[*] Source : %s || Destination: %s' % (packet[IP].src,packet[IP].dst)
         hexdump(packet[TCP].payload)

sniff(filter="tcp port 80 and host 10.0.0.21", prn=packet_callback, store=0)
```

This shows HTTP packets content from a specified host, but only *incoming* ones. If I adapt the IP to mine, I can see all of them.

This is a wireless interface I am listening on. Interface is in monitor mode, using tcpdump I can see all packets from everyone.

System is Linux Mint 17.

Any hint greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think scapy is not to blame because your code is working fine on my system, I can see both sides' packets. Do you have firewall rules on yours?

Comment: nope, no firewall.